# Waiting for bot to be ready - Azure Web Channel ( POST to the bot's endpoint failed with HTTP status 500 )

Tags: c#, azure, botframework, azure-webapps

I have created one **Web App Bot in Azure with Luis template** and service using **C# SDK** . Then I downloaded the source code of this sample bot from Azure and build the solution in Visual Studio and republished the bot in Azure app service after adding one more dialog.
I also added respective keys for **BotFilesecret** and **BotFilePath** before publishing the code. 
When I try to check the response of bot in web chat channel in Azure then I see **"waiting for bot to be ready"** message and the operation keeps processing but it's stuck there and doesn't loads the web chat.
**When I checked the Application Insights I can see the System exceptions getting logged with directline client; error 500** .

Call Stack for the Exception As Logged in Application Insights is as follows:

> **Microsoft.Bot.Schema.BotException** at: Microsoft.Bot.ChannelConnector.BotAPI+d__31.MoveNext (Microsoft.Bot.ChannelConnector, Version=3.2.2.5, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null)
>   **Inner exception System.Exception** handled at Microsoft.Bot.ChannelConnector.BotAPI+d__31.MoveNext:
>      at Microsoft.Bot.ChannelConnector.BotAPI+d__31.MoveNext (Microsoft.Bot.ChannelConnector, Version=3.2.2.5, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null)

I have no idea why is this happening . The web app bot uses the latest C# Bot SDK V4.

Please check application insights exception details as shown in Azure:
[image: POST to the bot's endpoint failed with HTTP status 500]

[image: Exception Properties]

Earlier I was getting the below 404 Resource Not Found error in Azure which is fixed now:

[image: Erorr 404 Resource Not Found]

Comment: Happy to try and help, but there's just not enough information here to act on. Can you update the question with the full details of the exceptions you're seeing being logged?

Comment: @Drew Hi, please check my updated issue with relevant exception details

Comment: What u r showing here appears to be the Bot Framework Service reporting exceptions when trying to deliver messages _to your bot_. What we need is the exceptions that are actually happening _in your bot_. Is your bot itself hooked up to Application Insights? If not u would need to turn on application logging in the Azure Web App and use something like Log Streaming to see what's happening. I suspect there's a problem w/your start up code, probably something w/the `.bot` file/secret. I know u said u set these, but maybe share a screenshot of the appsettings and paste in your `Startup.cs` code.

Comment: Log Stream section of the App Service linked to the Web App shows **IIS Detailed Error - 503.0 - Service Unavailable**.Detailed information: this error occurs when the worker process was unable to start.This could be due to an invalid identity or configuration, or because the concurrent request limit was reached.**Most likely causes **: An invalid identity in the application pool could cause this error.The application pool is no longer running because of configuration or reaching application failure limits.The concurrent application request limit was reached.

Comment: Also,the bot is linked with application insights

Comment: Ok, yeah, so your bot is just failing to start up completely resulting in a `503` error and Application Insights isn't going to be able to help us. Can you update your question with the `web.config` that should have been published for your app please?

Comment: I think, I got the issue, there's a reported bug for .bot and startup.cs files whose property is set as **Do Not Copy** to the output directory by default in the downloaded source code from Azure Template bot. I changed it to **Always copy** for the Startup.cs file which was not getting published to Azure from the Visual Studio.

Comment: That would do it every time. You should have seen an exception in the log stream about this though. It would only be on first hit, so you'd need to be watching the stream, restart the web app and then trigger first hit to start it up.

Comment: Thanks for guidance, you are right. The exception was mentioned indirectly in log stream (as added in comments above in detailed information) this was solved by copying Startup.cs file to published solution to Azure.